# golang map value returned by value or reference?

Tags: go

let's I have a map with key of string and value of pointer to a struct

```
type Entity struct{}
entity := &Entity{}
m := map[string]*Entity{"foo":entity}
```

I get the value and delete the entry later

```
en := m["foo"]
delete(m, "foo")
```

my question is that will the memory be garbage collected since the pointer to it is removed from the map? On the other note, I have the new pointer **en** before I delete the entry, it's a copy of the pointer also points to the same memory location, so the memory will not be garbage collected even the map entry is deleted? I am confused, help appreciated.

Comment: thanks to @icza for pointing to another post already has answers.

Comment: This code snippet shows that the memory is not garbage collected if another pointer is used to store the address
https://play.golang.org/p/YC4ax6k6dm

Comment: I don’t see how this is entirely a dupe - does getting an entry into a map return a pointer to the entry or a copy? Seems in my test it returns a copy which would be really crap

Answer (score 0):

Go's current implementation is a [parallel mark-and-sweep](https://blog.golang.org/go15gc) garbage collector.

To be precise on the scope where `entity` is declared, this object won't be garbaged collected, by the same reason you mentioned - after the deletion from the map there still is a reference to the object.

The state of the map is internal, and it will only be removed from there after the deletion operation.